# How to interpret / diagnose pdftk error message

Tags: pdf, macos

Context: Catalina (zsh is default)

The drop and drag instructions were followed per: http://hildstrom.com/projects/2011/08/bates-number-a-pdf/index.html#mac

[image]

Attempts to follow the procedure first returned:

[image]

Terminal then returned:

[image]

```
ctivityReport.pdf"; exit
user@JUPITER ~ % '/private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/596EF513-EE76-40D6-A64E-E9667AEAF23F/d/bates-label-a-pdf.app/'../bates-label-a-pdf.sh "/Users/user/Desktop/Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf"; exit
zsh: no such file or directory: /private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/596EF513-EE76-40D6-A64E-E9667AEAF23F/d/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh

[Process completed]
```

The goal is to understand why the procedure did not return the expected .pdf file and any actionable remedy.  I suspect that there may be a security setting that may need to be configured. Thank you

## PION test results

per pion's instructions to overcome the AppTranslocation issue:

user@JUPITER bates-label-a-pdf % `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf`

CPU = Intel i3770 (not M1).  Execution returned `Bad CPU type in executable` errors:

```
user@JUPITER ~ % '/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/'../bates-label-a-pdf.sh "/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf"; exit
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 18: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 21: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../labeling/generate-labeling-pdf: Bad CPU type in executable
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 22: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
mv: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../labeling/labeling.pdf-compressed: No such file or directory
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 26: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Comment: The `pdftk` and `generate-labeling-pdf` executables are `Mach-O executable i386` and therefore will not run under **macOS Catalina**. They need to be `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` to run under **macOS Catalina**.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr: [App Translocation.](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html)**

The [Bates Label](http://hildstrom.com/projects/bates-number-a-pdf/#mac) solution that you linked was written for macOS 10.7-10.8. In macOS 10.12 Apple began restricting non-Mac App Store apps from running unsigned code. Instead, macOS will create a random disk image, copy the application onto it, and execute the app from that image. Any external resources that the app depends upon are not copied, so if the app expects them to be found at a path that's relative to the app's original binary, you will see "file not found" errors.

That's what appears to be happening in your case. Here is the sequence:

1. You downloaded and unzipped a tarball containing `bates-label-a-pdf.app`, an unsigned app.
2. When you attempted to run that app, macOS translocated it to a random path (`/private/var/folders/5s/5j5833_j41q5jw5qg42h3h6w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/596EF513-EE76-40D6-A64E-E9667AEAF23F/d/bates-label-a-pdf.app/`).
3. The app seems to be a wrapper for the `bates-label-a-pdf.sh` script, which the app was expecting to be found in the same directory as the app itself, hence the `../bates-label-a-pdf.sh` relative path specification.
4. Since macOS did not copy the external shell script when it translocated the app, the app can't find it, and you get your "*no such file or directory*" message.

One workaround is to remove the `com.apple.quarantine` extended filesystem attribute from the app before running it. I explain this in longer form in [Should I enter this command in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425060/should-i-enter-this-command-in-terminal/425068#425068). The command in your case would be:

`xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /path/to/app/location`

where you would replace `/path/to/app/location` with the actual filesystem path to `bates-label-a-pdf.app`, wherever you put it. (According to the author's web page, that is supposed to be `~/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app` but it's possible that you left it inside your `Downloads` folder instead.)

---

If you're curious, here is the script code inside the app:

[image: AppleScript code for the bates label app]

Comment: The shell scripts need to be put inside the app bundles - as well as the pdftk executable

Comment: @pion Thank you for a clear & understandable explanation. Please see the eponymous test results at the end of the OP.  Can you confirm that the App Translocation problem is no longer an obstacle?   I suspect that it is, however, I would like someone with more experience to confirm.  Thank you

Comment: @pion I believe that you included the script code inside the app so that the reader can evaluate security risk of running the app?

Comment: @mmmmmm  Thanks for your insigh.: Based on the last error message: does it confirm that the .sh and pdftk executable are in the app bundle?

Comment: No pdtkf and the .sh are not inside the app bundles - that is the problem - if they were they would be copied to the translocated path

Comment: @mmmmmm Your comment is the spark for a new question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/431410/187540   The subject matter is new to me.