# Where should .sh and pdftk be copied to in foo.app?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, automator, pdf

An attempt to run a third party script on Catalina is described: [How to interpret / diagnose pdftk error message](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/431385/187540)

Test results after executing `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf`:

```
user@JUPITER ~ % '/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/'../bates-label-a-pdf.sh "/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf"; exit
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 18: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 21: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../labeling/generate-labeling-pdf: Bad CPU type in executable
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 22: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
mv: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../labeling/labeling.pdf-compressed: No such file or directory
/Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../bates-label-a-pdf.sh: line 26: /Users/user/Desktop/bates-label-a-pdf/bates-label-a-pdf.app/../pdftk/bin/pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable
```

User ***mmmmmm*** commented: [The shell scripts need to be put inside the app bundles - as well as the pdftk executable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431400/187540) and confirms that pdftk is not in the .app.

The .zip file provided by the thirty party contains `pdftk` and other `labeling` functionality:

[image]

Is the remedy a simple matter of copying

1. foo.sh files into the respective foo.app files?
2. copying `labeling` and `pdftk` to a location with bates-label-a-pdf.app?  Where exactly?
3. modifying the .plist?

Contents of ***application bundle*** bates-label-a-pdf.app:
[image]

If yes, then an example to follow example would be appreciated.

Comment: In essence yes see [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html) fior overview of where things go.  See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script I don't know about droplets

Comment: The `main.scpt` in the `bates-label-a-pdf.app` _application bundle_ and the `bates-label-a-pdf.sh` are editable and as such just make the appropriate edits if you want to include the `labeling` and `pdftk` _folders_ and the `bates-label-a-pdf.sh` _script_ within the `Resources` _folder_  of the `bates-label-a-pdf.app` _application bundle_.

Comment: BTW The `pdftk` and `generate-labeling-pdf` executables are `Mach-O executable i386` and therefore will not run under **macOS Catalina**. They need to be `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` to run under **macOS Catalina**.